# How can I make a list of the top comments in a subreddit with PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I need to grab the top comments in a subreddit, from all time.

I have tried grabbing all the submissions, and iterating through them, but unfortunately the amount of posts you can get is limited to 1000.

I have tried using `Subreddit.get_comments`, but it returns only 25 comments.

So I am looking for a way around that.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to use [`get_comments`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=get_comments#praw.__init__.UnauthenticatedReddit.get_comments) with a parameter of `limit` set to `None` to get all available comments.  (By default, it uses the amount for the account, which is usually 25).  (The parameters that are used for `get_comments` include the ones for [`get_content`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/code_overview.html?highlight=get_comments#praw.__init__.BaseReddit.get_content), including `limit`).

However, this probably won't do what you want – `get_comments` (or more specifically `/r/subreddit/comments`) only offers a list of new comments or new gilded comments, not top comments.  And since `get_comments` also capped to 1000 comments, you'll have trouble building a full list of top comments.

So what you really want is the original algorithm – getting the list of top submissions and then the top comments of those.  It's not the perfect system (a low-scoring post might actually have a highly voted comment), but it's the best possible.

Here's some code:

```python
import praw

r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='top_comment_test')
subreddit = r.get_subreddit('opensource')
top = subreddit.get_top(params={'t': 'all'}, limit=25) # For a more potentially accurate set of top comments, increase the limit (but it'll take longer)
all_comments = []
for submission in top: 
    submission_comments = praw.helpers.flatten_tree(submission.comments)
    #don't include non comment objects such as "morecomments"
    real_comments = [comment for comment in submission_comments if isinstance(comment, praw.objects.Comment)]
    all_comments += real_comments

all_comments.sort(key=lambda comment: comment.score, reverse=True)

top_comments = all_comments[:25] #top 25 comments

print top_comments
```

Comment: Looks like `get_subreddit` and `get_top` are no longer in the current version of praw. For this to run with the latest version you'll need to remove the word `get`:
`subreddit = r.subreddit('opensource')`
`top = subreddit.top(params={'t': 'all'}, limit=25)`